# The dfs is not wroking

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

The problem I am seeing is that it **outputted** all of the **ways**, even the ones that **cannot reach the end**. *But that is not how DFS is supposed to work.*

As I know right now, **DFS** is within a **recursive call chain**, and when it goes deeper into the function, it should **remove** the ones that are **not correct** and keep the ones that **are correct**.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;
bool f = false;
ll map[10001][10001];
ll vis[10001][10001];
char endmap[10001][10001];
ll dx[] = {0 , 0 , 1 , -1};
ll dy[] = {-1, 1 , 0, 0};
ll n,m,x1,y1,x2,y2;
void dfs(ll fi, ll fj){
    if(fi == x2&&fj == y2){
        cout << "PATH FOUND!:" << endl;
        f = true;
        for(ll i1 = 1; i1<=n; i1++){
            for(ll j1 = 1; j1<= m; j1++){
                if(vis[i1][j1] == 1){
                    endmap[i1][j1] = '!';
                }
            }
        }
        endmap[1][1] = 'S';
        endmap[x2][y2] = 'E';
        for(ll i1 = 1; i1<=n; i1++){
            for(ll j1 = 1; j1<= m; j1++){
                cout << endmap[i1][j1] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }else{
        for(ll i = 0; i<4; i++){
            ll xx = fi + dx[i];
            ll yy = fj + dy[i];
            if (yy>=1&& xx >= 1 && vis[xx][yy] == 0 && xx <= n && yy <= n && map[xx][yy] == 0){
                vis[xx][yy] = 1;
                dfs(xx,yy);
            }
        }
    }

}
int main(){
    cout << "Enter the length and the width of the map: ";
    cin >> n >> m;
    for(ll i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        for(ll j = 1; j<=m; j++){
            endmap[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
    cout << "Draw the map: " << endl;
    for(ll i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        for(ll j = 1; j<=m; j++){
            cin >> map[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Enter the start(two numbers) and the end(two numbers):";
    cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
    cout << endl << "EXECUTING..." << endl;
    dfs(x1,y1);
    if(!f){
        cerr << "ERROR! " << "Found on: " << __TIME__ << endl << "NO EXIT/PATH FOUND!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input is like this:

```
Enter the length and the width of the map: 9 9
Draw the map:
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
Enter the start(two numbers) and the end(two numbers):1 1 9 9
```

And the output:

```
EXECUTING...
PATH FOUND!:
S 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! 0
0 ! 0 0 0 0 0 ! 0
0 ! ! ! 0 ! ! ! 0
0 ! 0 ! 0 ! 0 ! 0
0 ! ! 0 0 0 0 ! 0
0 0 ! 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 ! ! ! ! 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 ! ! ! E
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: No no no no NO! Don't use so-called "competition" sites to learn anything but really bad coding habits and often also invalid code. Invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and take computer science classes. Then after a few years, learning multiple languages and all the basic CS algorithms and data-structures, use such sites a kind of programmers crossword puzzles or brain-teasers. But until then don't even look at such a site.

Comment: On another note, "deep filtering search"? That seems like something completely different from depth first search. For future questions please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please try to get the acronyms correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herein lies the problem, all locations visited by DFS are marked:

```
if(vis[i1][j1] == 1){
    endmap[i1][j1] = '!';
}
```

You should record the current path with a data structure (such as vector) in the DFS input parameter, and when DFS can reach the end, mark all coordinates in the vector with an exclamation point.

Comment: But for DFS, I've heard in some tutorials or websites that it can sort of **retreat** the ways not working and keep the ones working

Comment: Yes, it can, using exactly the trick I mentioned

Comment: The char array you use is a global variable, and the coordinates that don't actually reach the end point (but are marked as visiteded in the vis array) have also been modified.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, it's called Depth-First Search, not "deep filtering search".

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The path you want to search is 17 squares, which is the shortest, and the other paths are shorter than that, so all the paths will be searched.
I think there is a way to find the shortest number of routes without changing the route mark.